# How to take specific time interval on videos from Camera Roll on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

I need to take specific time interval of the video. For instance; last 40 seconds of it. I have searched for it. But could not find even a clue.

Could you please help or show me a way to do it.

BR,

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out:

```
        AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil]; 


        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:videoAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
        exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputURL];
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
        CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMake(startMilliseconds, 1000), CMTimeMake(endMilliseconds - startMilliseconds, 1000));
        exportSession.timeRange = timeRange;

        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            switch (exportSession.status) {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                    // Custom method to import the Exported Video
                    [self loadAssetFromFile:exportSession.outputURL];
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                    //
                    NSLog(@"Failed:%@",exportSession.error);
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                    //
                    NSLog(@"Canceled:%@",exportSession.error);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }];
```